# How to obtain the filesize of a binary file without opening it as it is continuously being modified

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, chunks

I have a binary file which is being modified and expanded continuously by a sensor unit, data in the file is being stored in the format `np.float32`. I need to read how many such data 'chunks' have been written by reading the total length of the file. What is the most optimum way to do this. I currently have the following piece of code which works fine initially but slows down (as expected when the file size increases). This is because I am opening the file every time.
Is there a way to do this using `os.path.getsize('file_path')` ?

```
with open(data_file, 'rb') as fid:
    return(len(np.fromfile(fid, np.float32)))
```

Comment: Can you modify the sensor/writing app?  If you can then have that fsync() regularly and report bufferd data+file size to a pipe. Reading the pipe will give an exact size.

Comment: The sensor program is written by a third party so I won't be able to modify it.

Comment: Can you get the sensor program to write all it's output data to STDOUT rather than OS file access?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do following:

```
import os

print(os.path.getsize("path/of/your/file"))
```

This will print size of file in bytes.

Hope this helps

Comment: This won't produce accurate results. Files are buffered in memory before being committed to disk.  You will get the size on disk since the last buffer flush but not the actual file size written by the sensor.  e.g. If the sensor app OS has a 1Mbyte write buffer and the writing application does not call os.fsync(fd) then the file will read as zero size until 1MB has been written.

Answer (score 0):

`os.path.getsize` gives you the size in bytes. The size of `np.float32` is 4 bytes as the `32` refers to the number of bits, but you can also get the size in bytes by

```
>>> np.dtype(np.float32).itemsize
4
```

Dividing the file size by item size will give you the number of items.